# Upload image to facebook from SD card in android

Tags: android, facebook

I Can't able to upload the images on the facebook from SD card...I used below code....but it did not give me error but at the same time it did not upload the images

```
     byte[] data = null;
     try {
         FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filepath);
         BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();                   
            options.inSampleSize = 2; 
         Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
         data = baos.toByteArray();  
      } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
         e.printStackTrace();
         Log.d("onCreate", "debug error  e = " + e.toString());
      }     

         Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
         params.putString("method", "photos.upload");  
         params.putByteArray("picture", data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below Snippet for Post Image from SDCard :

Convert your image to bitmap and proceed

```
private void postToWall() {   
    AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new   AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);  // where bm is bitmap from Sdcard
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    Bundle param = new Bundle();
    param = new Bundle();
    param.putString("message", "All");
    param.putString("filename", "TEst");
    param.putByteArray("image", byteArray);
    mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", param, "POST", new fbRequestListener(), null);
  }

  public class fbRequestListener implements RequestListener {

      @Override
      public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Log.d("RESPONSE",""+response);

      }

      @Override
      public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Log.d("RESPONSE",""+e);

      }

      @Override
      public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e,
              Object state) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Log.d("RESPONSE",""+e);

      }

      @Override
      public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e,
              Object state) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

      }

      @Override
      public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          Log.d("RESPONSE",""+e);

      }

      }
```

Comment: {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}

Comment: pass additional parameter : param.putString("access_token", "Your Access token");

Comment: Why it is needed when i already signed in? anyway, its performing request facebook object which we authorize and already having access_token

Comment: For some cases we need to query access token , in this case i am not sure , Above code worked for me with out querying access token.. My guess is problem with access_token..

Comment: @TejasGolwala You have to save access token.Hope you are doing it?

Comment: after passing this i got "error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190}} in logcat..

Comment: Problem in your access_token , ensure that you are following this to save properly : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#token

Comment: I have just copied and tried all the codes available on stack overflow. I have tried that code also. But image is not uploading. What issue is this?? Again the method onComplete is called and response is some id like 4129400054..... What should I do now?? There is no image on my wall

Comment: @TejasGolwala  You to check user Album for photo , hope you are doing it

Comment: Where you are checking your picture after posted?

Comment: I have tried the code. And it is working. Thanks Venky. Images are uploaded into albums.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this:

```
 mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(fbObj);  
  mAsyncRunner.request(null, parameters, "POST",
                        new RequestListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onMalformedURLException(
                                    MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFileNotFoundException(
                                    FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e,
                                    Object state) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Log.i("upload", "image uploaded!!!! " + response);
                            }
                        }, null);
```

Comment: i Added this code but on facebook dialog it shows me "Error Occured" and Please try again later.

Comment: {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}

Comment: you didnt login? you directly uploading images?

Comment: checked permissions array?. or is it showing logcat that connection refused?