# Posting Images on Facebook from SD Card in Android Programmatically

Tags: android, facebook

I have checked all the related posts on stack overflow and facebook dev site. I don't know what is the issue, why im unable to post a photo on facebook from Android.

Here is the code.

```
public static void AuthFB()
    {
        facebook = new Facebook(YOUR_APP_ID); 
        facebook.authorize((Activity) myCxt, new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                postImageonWall("/mnt/sdcard/cmtdd.png");
                Log.d("FB","Yes Called");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Now on authentication complete I am posting image to wall. Here is the code.

```
public static void postImageonWall(String FilePath) {

    Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/cmtdd.png");
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();   

         Bundle params = new Bundle(); 
         params.putString("method", "photos.upload");  
         params.putByteArray("picture", data);

         AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
         mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", new RequestListener() {

            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
                Log.d("request RequestListener", "debug onMalformedURLException");
            }

            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                Log.d("request RequestListener", "debug onIOException");
            }

            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
                Log.d("request RequestListener", "debug onFileNotFoundException");
            }

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                Log.d("request RequestListener", "debug onFacebookError");
            }

            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                 Log.d("request RequestListener", "debug onComplete");
            }
         }, null);

}
```

The method onComplete is called. But There is nothing uploaded to my wall. 
Can any one tell me where is the mistake?

Comment: Just now i answered for same question .Check it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113500/upload-image-to-facebook-from-sd-card-in-android

Comment: I have just copied and tried all the codes available on stack overflow. I have tried that code also. But image is not uploading. What issue is this?? Again the method onComplete is called and response is some id like 4129400054..... What should I do now?? There is no image on my wall.

Comment: Image will be in your Album not in your wall..

Comment: and what if I wanted to post it on my wall? What is the use if it is not shown to other people i.e friends?

Comment: If you image is in Server , we can post in wall.. @Jawad Amjad

Comment: Venky I just came to know that when we upload image in albums we must aprove them to be shown on Wall. Is there any way to accept them automatically. In this way they will be shown on the wall.